# How to save the config of rqt_bag

Tags: ros, gui, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I usually use rqt_bag to debug.view the image and plot some sensors data.However,There are more than 5 topic to be watched.everytime i need to open the topic again and again.could i save the config.next time,when i open the rosbag,the topic is auto be viewed.thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351273/how-to-save-the-config-of-rqt_bag/) by [jzx](https://answers.ros.org/users/54356/jzx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am afraid that rqt_bag doesn't support that.

But you may use [PlotJuggler](https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler) and the so called "layout files" that have been created specifically for that purpose.

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0